# Clean flash without SDCard

Tags: internal-storage, rom-flashing, custom-roms, sd-card, samsung-galaxy-nexus

So, I want to flash a new rom with gapps.
I've done this before, but I always did a factory reset and flashed the new rom which was in the downloads folder in my phone.
I was wondering, if I wipe my data and system via twrp, will my internal partition be wiped? Because if it does, I have nothing to flash cause that's where my rom is stored.
I have the Samsung Galaxy Nexus which doesn't have a sdcard, so that's not an option.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah ADB will not work within the bootloader/fastboot mode. ADB only works within an OS such as android OS or recovery. The bootloader/fastboot loads the system so it is before the system. You need to use fastboot prototocal so to see your devices you need to throw > fastboot devices

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to worry if your internal storage gets wiped.

There is another way called "ADB Sideload" which allows you to push and install a zip from your computer using CMD (Windows) or Terminal (Linux)

**Steps to use ADB Sideload**

> 1. Have a recovery installed on your device that supports ADB sideload like TWRP 2.3 or higher. The stock recovery on JellyBean and later maybe have it.
> 2. Have newer ADB binaries installed on your computer
> 3. Set the device into ADB sideload mode. In TWRP you do this by going to Advanced then ADB Sideload.
> 4. From the command prompt (CMD), type `adb sideload /path/to/rom.zip`

[Reference](https://twrp.me/faq/ADBSideload.html)

Comment: So my downloads folder will still be there when I wipe system and data? And I used this method to unlock my Phone. Well, not that method but ADB. Anyway, the problem there is, ADB doesn't detect my Phone. The strage thing is: it dóes detect it when it is ON, not in fastboot mode. The other thing, fastboot DOES detect my Phone. Isn't that a bit strange?

Comment: As @Bo Lawson said...ADB can not detect in fastboot/bootloader. It only work if your system is booted. But you can use adb in recovery by sideload to flash zips without using sd or internal memory.And about the downloads folder, It will still be there unless you select wipe internal data while formatting system or doing full wipe. Hope it helps.